# QGIS and Google map doesn't match/lineup!

Tags: qgis, openlayers, google-maps, coordinates, cartography

I am trying to draw a map but in QGIS the map doesn't correctly show one of my study area (Station-4) correctly; however, the Google Map does.

What should I do now to get a correct map (Station-4) just like the one shown by Google Map. [image]

Comment: Coordinates are:   
St-I 41° 0'31.42"N / 38°22'3.82"E  
St-II 40°57'59.64"N /  38°22'5.35"E  
St-III 40°55'26.26" N /  38°22'8.12"E  
St-IV 40°55'12.16"N / 38°22'48.72"E

Comment: Please do not add information to your question in the comments section. Rather please edit your question and update it with additional information. Could you please explain what the images you are showing are? What is the source of your points? Did you digitise them off Google Earth, were they collected in the field, were they surveyed?

Comment: @KeaganAllan Thanks for the answer. The first image (Grey in color) is made using QGIS map but it shows wrongly the position of Station-4. But when I match it with Google map, the Google Map provided correct one. I don't have any idea about digitise.

Comment: You have dramatically different resolutions of coastline between the data you are using in QGIS and that in Google.  So, my first suggestion is get some higher resolution coastline data.  OSM is usually better than GSHHS

Comment: From the looks of things. The left map has a different backdrop than the map on the right. The point may be correct, it just appears to be incorrect because of the coarse nature of your backdrop. It looks like the backdrop on the left image was created at a very high level, meaning it doesn't really represent what is on the ground and should be used for an overview map rather than detailed mapping.

Comment: @MappaGnosis Yes that is the problem I am facing. Especially station-4 is shown (QGIS map) completely wrong.  I am usin "Natural_Earth" map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Natural Earth quick start kit data is designed for use at a much coarser scale than your map. The map isn't *wrong*, it's just insufficiently detailed for your needs.

### The solution is to replace the coastline layer with a more detailed layer.

One way is to search the internet for a replacement layer. A quick google of the phrase "turkey national boundary shapefile" led me to [this shapefile](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/turkey-shapefile), which looks legitimate as far as I can tell. You can also find administrative boundaries for any country in the world [here](http://www.gadm.org/country). You may need to try more than one layer before you find one that is sufficiently detailed.

The second way is to digitize the coastline by hand from the Google Map layer that you already have. This means creating a new polygon layer and editing it to create the country boundary. If you need instructions on digitizing in QGIS, [many tutorials](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/digitizing_basics.html) can by found by a quick internet search.

Answer (score 2):

The fault is the openlayers plugin. Delete it asap and install the QuickMapServices plugin instead.

Comment: I also used OSM, both OSM and Google map (openlayers) provided a similar map (correct one).

Comment: I also use QuickMapServices now and there was no mistake means it also produces a map just like the one provided by Google map.

Comment: If this answer is correct, please mark it answered by clicking the green tick. It will help others who may face similar question / problems you have encountered.

Comment: Dear @KeaganAllan but i didn't find/get any solution! The problem persist.

Comment: Please anyone can tell me the solution? I downloaded a map for Qgis (Natural Earth quick start kit) then I start working with it but it shows my study area wrongly (left image in above attachment).